# AWS s3 cli sync multipart upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, command-line-interface, multipart

AWS s3 cli sync can use multipart upload option?

on-premise server sync to s3 using AWS cli sync

but, speed is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the `aws` command (and not e.g. `s3cmd`): Yes, sync uses multipart upload by default. From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html#using-s3-commands-managing-objects):

> All high-level commands that involve uploading objects into an Amazon S3 bucket (aws s3 cp, aws s3 mv, and aws s3 sync) automatically perform a multipart upload when the object is large

I guess the slowness is caused by another factor, e.g. your bandwidth is low (check e.g. with [speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net/) or it is already saturated